# Percentage of iOS users authenticated with iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I am currently considering CloudKit as a backend for a new app I am writing.

With Apple claiming [782 million iCloud users and a billion active iOS devices](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/02/12/apple-music-passes-11m-subscribers-as-icloud-hits-782m-users), the idea of leveraging iCloud login sounds great.

My assumption was that it means pretty much anybody can just download my app and start using it without having to go through an annoying sign-up process.

So, out of curiosity I have checked the iCloud adoption rate in an app I currently work on, in the store, with a few thousands users.

Here is what I do to check for iCloud:

```
- (void)checkForiCloud {
    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {
        if (error.code == CKErrorNotAuthenticated) {
            user.hasiCloud = NO;
        } else if (recordID && recordID.recordName) {
            user.hasiCloud = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

The result is that **less than 60%** have iCloud set up. If I have to ask 40% of my users to create or log in an iCloud account to use my app, it kind of defeats the purpose.

So here is my question:

**Has anybody seen similar stats or know where I can find good numbers on the percentage of iOS users who have an iCloud account set up on their device?**

Comment: Interesting. iCloud is often used for syncing across multiple devices, so I'd guess a lot of iCloud users have more than one iOS device. This means that Apple's figures don't necessarily conflict with your own observations...

Comment: It's worth noting that users need to have iCloud Drive in order to use CloudKit so the number of users eligible for CloudKit is probably a fair bit smaller that 782 million

Comment: That's a good point @Luke, iCloud is available for users of iOS 5 or later but iCloud Drive is only available in iOS 8 and later...

Comment: And many users (like me) have refused to "upgrade" to iCloud Drive for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After 20 days and gathering data for about 5k users, the percentage of users authenticated with iCloud is stabilising at around **73%**.

Comment: Can I ask if you're still collecting this data? I'd be interested to know if it's changed much since you posted?

Comment: Yeah 2.5 years later I'd love to see if/how this has changed.

Comment: Plus one on the above requests - my guess is that it is only increasing.